# Ruby on Rails -- Jquery.countdown.timer issue ( timer starts from 30 Days)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, timer

I wanted to use this jquery plugin for Timing an exam. The ending time is:"2018-07-09 11:14:44 +0000" but when I use the timer instead of showing that there are 20 mins or 2 hours left it shows 30 days 20 hours and 58 mins. What am I doing wrong??? 
My application.js:

```
function setCountdownTimer(element, year, month, day, hour, minute, second) {
  var date = new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
  $(element).countdown({until: date});
}
```

My view file:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var element = '#countDownTimer';
    var year = <%= @exam.ending_date_and_time.year %>;
    var month = <%= @exam.ending_date_and_time.month %>;
    var day = <%= @exam.ending_date_and_time.day %>;
    var hour = <%= @exam.ending_date_and_time.strftime('%H').to_i %>;
    var minute = <%= @exam.ending_date_and_time.strftime('%M').to_i %>;
    var second = <%= @exam.ending_date_and_time.strftime('%S').to_i %>;
    setCountdownTimer(element, year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
});
</script>
<div id="countDownTimer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Months are zero based, so you have to turn 1 - 12 to 0 - 11:

```
new Date(year, month - 1 /*!*/, /*...*/)
```

Also note that:

> Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one argument, the specified arguments represent local time. If UTC is desired, use new Date(Date.UTC(...)) with the same arguments. ~ [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: then the timer says 0 hours 0 mins and 0 seconds

Comment: @R.IOOp 11:14 was one and a half hours ago (at least for me)